# subprocess module: using the call method with tempfile objects

Tags: python, subprocess

I have created temporary named files, with the tempfile libraries NamedTemporaryFile method.
I have written to them flushed the buffers, and I have not closed them (or else they might go away)

I am trying to use the `subprocess` module to call some shell commands using these generated files.

`subprocess.call('cat %s' % f.name)` always fails saying that the named temporary file does not exist.

`os.path.exists(f.name)` always returns true.
I can run the cat command on the file directly from the shell.

Is there some reason the `subprocess` module will not work with temporary files?

Is there any way to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was not using shell=True so I changed to it.  Now the error comes up saying, '/bin/sh : No such file or directory'

Comment: The files are also not being deleted.  I can open up another tab in my terminal and cat the files just fine.  Like i said, os.path.exists still says the files are there.  It is something with the subprocess module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using shell=True option for subprocess?

Comment: I was being stupid, setting shell to true fixed the errors but there was another file not found error, where the file actually didnt exist.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make your `NamedTemporaryFile`s with the optional parameter `delete=False`? That way you can safely close them knowing they won't disappear, use them normally afterwards, and explicitly unlink them when you're done. This way everything will work cross-platform, too.